# Ocamlbuild override the default options

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

My installation of OCaml does not recognize #!, therefore camlp4o cannot be ran standalone. It must be invoked as "ocamlrun camlp4o".

I try to add a flag in the plugin. But the new flag is simply added to the existing flag.

The result is that ocamlbuild will invoke the compiler with

"-pp camlp4o ocamlrun camlp4o".

A working workaround is to introduce a new tag 'my_camlp4o'. However, the documentation of ocamlbuild did mention the capability of 'overriding' defaults. It seems ocamlc, ocamlopt can be overridden. But can we override camlp4o? Can it be done in plugins?

Comment: what is the command that you want ocamlbuild to execute?

Answer (score 2):

There is support for changing defaults in Ocamlbuild, through the `-ocamlc <command>`, `-ocamldep <command>` etc. command-line options. Unfortunately, camlp4 is currently not part of the set of customizable commands. Could you please use the [issue tracker](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view_all_bug_page.php) to request this feature?

(In the meantime I recommend a workaround, eg. you replace the `ocamlrun` executable in your PATH by an executable script that does the right thing.)

**Edit**

Another workaround is to do all your compilation through `ocamlfind`, which has support for overriding the camlp4 command (see [the documentation](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.2.8/doc/guide-html/x412.html)), and can be used as a basis for all ocamlbuild command with the `-use-ocamlfind` option. Unfortunately, ocamlfind itself only supports preprocessing at compile-time (when invoking the actual compiler), not stand-alone source-to-source processing, so that may not cover your own use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will request this feature.